# CORS in Grafana API

Tags: reactjs, api, grafana, grafana-api

I want to enable cors on grafana so that I can make POST request on a react APP using grafana API. My issue is I can't set cors on grafana.

I have tried to edit the defaults.ini file for grafana but the issue of CORS Not enabled keeps persisting. How do I enable cors in Grafana?

Comment: You can enable CORS by modifying custom.ini like this:
[server.custom_response_headers]
Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "host:port"
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No built-it CORS in Grafana, as discussed [here](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-allow-access-control-allow-origin-for-all-the-apis/2045) and many times repeated over.

You'll need to setup Reverse proxy that will handle CORS for you.General example of nginx config for this can be found [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html).

Obviously nginx is just a suggestion: you can use any reverse proxy of your liking.

Official reference on how to configure Grafana to run behind reverse proxy [here](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/).

Comment: Thanks, let me check on those links that you've shared and see if I will solve my issue.